# Genealogy Relationship Mapping why base on families

Tags: database-schema, database-design, genealogy

I am developing a geneaology application, and am currently at the stage of modelling relationships between individuals.

Based on my research, I have noted that most of the mappings of relationships are based on families (father + mother) and so I would like to understand the underlying reasoning behind this before I adopt it blindly.

Since my project is patriarchal, I assume that as soon as a person adds a father, then that creates a new family

Comment: At first glance a Person is a child of Person and Person. The real challenges are adoptions and single sex couples; in your case the lesbian variant, given the patriachality.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling adoptions (tricky), lesbian, partners, friends are catered for else where. Since they may not have any children, but it seems like most applications create a family (father-mother-child). Same happens when you add a child with no father, a family is created

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most Genealogy software vendors decided to follow the model that professional genealogists use. The basis is a [family group sheet](http://www.beholdgenealogy.com/blog/?p=1079), that includes the father at the top left, the mother at the top right, and the children below.

The database structure then chosen is to have records of two types: Individuals and Families. These are exemplified by [the GEDCOM standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GEDCOM) which is used to transfer genealogy data between programs.

Then they use what is called [a lineage-linked data structure](http://www.cyndislist.com/lineage-linked/briefly-defined/). This structure has two connections:

1. The Individual will link to the family in which they are a husband or a wife (a FAMS link) and the Family will link back to the two individuals (a HUSB and a WIFE link).
2. The Individual will link to the families who are their parents, either blood or adopted (a FAMC), and each Family will link back to their children (CHIL links).

Once you develop your program, make sure it will be able to read and write GEDCOM.

Comment: Thank you for the concise clarifications